# What more should universities do to limit student exposure to dangerous speech?

Tags: diversity

It's 2017.  Universities should be a safe space for students of all cultures, creeds, gender identities, sexualities, nationalities, economic backgrounds, or other intersectional marginalized categorizations.  This is not the case.

What more should Universities, and especially the faculty, do to preserve Universities as safe spaces and as open and inclusive environments?

Comment: I voted to close this because it is clearly not a serious question asked in good faith, but just a way for you to express your opinion about higher education. See the [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 14):

Your fundamental premise is flawed. Universities are not a place to shield people from things that exist in the world. They are a place to *learn* what is in the world and how to face those things successfully. You do that through exposure, understanding and discussion. People at college age are still learning what they believe, and that process is significantly retarded if their beliefs aren't challenged.

Safe spaces are themselves the bad idea. They prevent young people from learning how to take responsibility for their own well-being at a critical time in their transition to adulthood. Universities should do *less* to infantilize their students, not more.

Comment: Perhaps it should be clearer what OP intends "safe spaces" to signify?

Comment: I can not even right now.  On a stack exchange such as this are you seriously condoning violent speech?  Many Universities such a Cambridge and others provide counseling and other resources for exactly the type of rhetoric you're attempting to defend.  Cambridge is also renowned for banning speakers from campus when they condone potentially hateful rhetoric against intersectional oppression.  They even allow students to retake tests when they are triggered by violent speech.  Violence in a University setting is unacceptable.  Are you implying you are a better educator than those at Cambridge?

Comment: The philosophy that has grown out of intersectionality is divisive and conflicts directly with the self-responsibility core to adulthood. 
The idea that **speech is not violence** is the premise underlying the difference between civilized society and barbarism. It allows us to talk through our differences rather than going straight to killing each other like animals.
The *very few* people who are actually "triggered" by speech either due to mental illness or unhealed mental trauma should absolutely seek counseling where they will be exposed to amounts they can handle so they can recover.

Comment: Cambridge and many other universities are providing safe spaces because of activist and legal pressure from culturally Marxist postmodernists--descendants of the Frankfurt School, Derrida and others--not because it's the right thing to do for quality education. Outside their own circles they are *infamous*, not "renowned" for banning speakers from campus, as doing so implies they are afraid their ideas won't hold up under scrutiny.

Comment: You can't expect students to *effectively* oppose proven bad ideas such as Nazi Fascism or Stalinist Communism *unless they face them*. They have to *learn* what those things are, and through discussion and argument, learn to express why they disagree without physically hurting people. If you shield them completely from the ideas, they won't know their ideological enemy and will have no defenses when those same ideas come back with a different name tag.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption why do you think it's gotten like this?

Comment: "Why" is a question that could be answered at many different levels and most are too long and involved for a comment thread. For the philosophical history level and some political level explanations I'd recommend the book "Explaining Postmodernism" by Stephen Hicks as a good place to start.

Comment: Another proximate cause is that the social science departments driving these ideas are ridiculously politically biased (I've seen ratios from 40:1 to over 267:1) and have in practice rejected the Enlightenment philosophy foundational to science. The goals have shifted ideas from inquiry to a positive feedback loop of activists creating activists to *push* their ideas and stomp out disagreement by any means. Yet another proximate cause is the cumulative effect of the fact that politics and temperament have strong correlations, so many balancing personality types have become wholly excluded.

Comment: -1 These arguments, of course, with the unwritten assumption that such speech does not _literally make life more dangerous_ for students at that university. Not everybody gets the luxury to just sit back and let the population decide who's right in a fair and even discourse.

Comment: To be very clear, *it's obvious to most people*, that the principle of free speech does not defend anyone who says "All of you go outside and punch every ____ you see right now!" Avoiding physical violence, by moving all fights into words instead of actions, is the point of free speech, so directly calling for physical violence conflicts with that. However, speech that merely offends or upsets--however strongly--but falls short of a call for physical violence *must not* be inhibited. To do so is to remove student's chance to learn to grapple with an idea.

Comment: You sound like you're against fair and even discourse. You want *uneven*, *unfair* discourse?? What then *when* your ideological opponents came into control of the discourse (as often happens)? If you don't believe your ideas will win when the discourse is fair and even, why should anyone think those ideas have merit? Letting the population decide *is what's supposed to happen*. It's one of the goals. It's how individuals agree to create society rather than fight. And it's not "a luxury" for anyone--convincing even a few takes a lot of effort.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption It's never that obvious. There's a long, grey, very transient line between what counts as hate speech and what counts as education, and many people have made a very lucrative living convincing people that certain populations shouldn't be allowed to live or possess rights without making it as obvious as you did. We're still having a national debate on whether literal eugenics proponents deserve an academic platform. But this is giving the question more credit than it deserves, I'll say no more.

Comment: The idea of "hate speech" impossibly requires listeners to first accurately ascertain and then cooperatively agree on the speaker's primary *internal* motivation. It's an amorphous standard with no basis in publicly available fact. That's why it's a bad measure leaving tons of grey area, and why hate speech codes should be opposed. As long as it doesn't violate the call-to-violence standard, highly controversial speech, including that motivated by hate, is exactly the sort of thing that students need to have the chance to confront and intellectually defeat in order to mature.